# how do I iterate through internal properties in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, access-modifiers

```
public class TestClass
{
        public string property1 { get; set; }
        public string property2 { get; set; }

        internal string property3 { get; set; }
        internal string property4 { get; set; }
        internal string property5 { get; set; }
}
```

I can iterate through the properties with the following loop, but it only shows public properties. I need all the properties.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(TestClass).GetProperties())
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024006/how-do-i-look-up-the-internal-properties-of-a-c-sharp-class-protected-protecte for a variant for this.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need to specify that you don't just need the public properties, using the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) accepting [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx):

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(TestClass)
             .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | 
                            BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                            BindingFlags.Public))
{
    //do something
}
```

Add `BindingFlags.Static` if you want to include static properties.

The parameterless overload only returns public properties.

Comment: Giving NonPublic and Instance will hide prop 1 and prop 2, you need both, NonPublic | Public for all properties

Comment: anyway to select only protected or internal?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane: Not with binding flags, that I'm aware of. Just filter afterwards.

Comment: The piece it took me a little while to figure out is that once you're specifying any `BindingFlags`, you need to specify all `BindingFlags` necessary to identify the props you're interested in; specifically, without `BindingFlags.Instance` you won't match on any instance properties.

(other languages' introspection led me to expect "Instance" to be assumed)

Answer (score 13):

You need to change the [`BindingFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) on your call to [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx)

Try:

```
var instanceProperties = typeof(TestClass).GetProperties(
    BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
    BindingFlags.Instance
);
foreach(var instanceProperty in instanceProperties) {
    // a little something something for the instanceProperty
}
```

Comment: yeah, I had to add BindingFlags.Public as well

Answer (score 7):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx), private and internal are not recognized in Reflection API.

> To identify an internal method using Reflection, use the IsAssembly
>   property. To identify a protected internal method, use the
>   IsFamilyOrAssembly.

If You are writing some test units You might want to take a look at [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute. It allows you to specify which assembly can see internal properties.

And finally, do You really need to have internal properties...

Comment: yeah I do, it's wcf service class, I want the client to fill in some properties before sending it to the server, and rest of the properties to be filled in on the service.

Answer (score 3):

Use [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx)

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(TestClass)
        .GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

by specifying what bindingflags in GetProperties:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(TestClass).GetProperties(
      BindingFlags.Instance|
      BindingFlags.Public|
      BindingFlags.NonPublic))
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the internal properties of a type by querying the NonPublic properties and then filtering the Get methods of these by "IsAssembly".

"internal protected" properties have their getters marked as "IsFamilyOrAssembly", "protected" properties as "IsFamily", and 
"private" properties as marked with "IsPrivate":

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        private string Property2 { get; set; }

        public string Property9 { get; set; }
        private string Property10 { get; set; }

        protected internal string Property3 { get; set; }
        protected string Property4 { get; set; }
        internal string Property5 { get; set; }

        protected internal int Property6 { get; set; }
        protected int Property7 { get; set; }
        internal int Property8 { get; set; }

        internal static void ShowPropertyAccessScope(Type t)
        {

            foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-28} {1,15}", "Public property:", prop.Name);
            }

            var nonPublic = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

            foreach (var prop in nonPublic.Where(p => p.GetGetMethod(true)?.IsAssembly == true))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-28} {1,15}", "Internal property:", prop.Name);
            }

            foreach (var prop in nonPublic.Where(p => p.GetGetMethod(true)?.IsFamilyOrAssembly == true))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-28} {1,15}", "Internal protected property:", prop.Name);
            }

            foreach (var prop in nonPublic.Where(p => p.GetGetMethod(true)?.IsFamily == true))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-28} {1,15}", "Protected property:", prop.Name);
            }

            foreach (var prop in nonPublic.Where(p => p.GetGetMethod(true)?.IsPrivate == true))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-28} {1,15}", "Private property:", prop.Name);
            }
        }
        static void Main() 
        {
            ShowPropertyAccessScope(typeof(TestClass));
        }
    }
```