# How do I look up the internal properties of a C# class? protected? protected internal?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

If I have a C# class `MyClass` as below:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public int pPublic {get;set;}
        private int pPrivate {get;set;}
        internal int pInternal {get;set;}
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Debug.Assert(typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Length == 1);
            Debug.Assert(typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Length == 2);
            // internal?
            // protected?
            // protected internal?
        }
    }
}
```

The code above compiles are runs without any assertion failures. NonPublic returns the Internal and Private properties. There does not appear to be flags for the other accessibility types on [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx).

How do I get a list/array of only the properties that are internal? On a related note, but not necessary for my application, what about protected, or protected internal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you get the property infos with `BindingFlags.NonPublic`, you find the getter or setter by using `GetGetMethod(true)` and `GetSetMethod(true)`, respectively. You can then check the following properties (of the method info) to get the exact access level:

- `propertyInfo.GetGetMethod(true).IsPrivate` means private
- `propertyInfo.GetGetMethod(true).IsFamily` means protected
- `propertyInfo.GetGetMethod(true).IsAssembly` means internal
- `propertyInfo.GetGetMethod(true).IsFamilyOrAssembly` means protected internal
- `propertyInfo.GetGetMethod(true).IsFamilyAndAssembly` means private protected

and similarly for `GetSetMethod(true)` of course.

Remember that it is legal to have one of the accessors (getter or setter) more restricted than the other one. If there is just one accessor, its accessibility is the accessibility of the entire property. If both accessors are there, the *most* accessible one gives you the accessibility of the whole property.

Use `propertyInfo.CanRead` to see if it's OK to call `propertyInfo.GetGetMethod`, and use `propertyInfo.CanWrite` to see if it's OK to call `propertyInfo.GetSetMethod`. The `GetGetMethod` and `GetSetMethod` methods return `null` if the accessor does not exist (or if it is non-public and you asked for a public one).

Comment: Another option would be to call propertyInfo.GetGetMethod(true). i.e. propertyInfo.GetGetMethod(true).IsPrivate.  Also note that I had to call GetProperties like this to make it work GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);  GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic) by itself didn't work

Comment: @cgotberg Yes, I edited my answer to use `true` parameter. Otherwise it won't give you the non-public accessors. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) on MSDN.

Relevant quote:

> The C# keywords protected and internal have no meaning in IL and are
>   not used in the reflection APIs. The corresponding terms in IL are
>   Family and Assembly. To identify an internal method using reflection,
>   use the IsAssembly property. To identify a protected internal method,
>   use the IsFamilyOrAssembly.

Comment: That's about methods only, or properties as well?

Comment: I don't believe there's any difference.

Comment: I think there is, because both `IsAssembly` and `IsFamilyAndAssembly` are declared on `MethodBase` class, so they aren't available on `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I think it would be on the `PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod()` and `PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod()` which provide the `MethodInfo` objects representing the underlying method. Also, you might need to hit the overload where you pass in a `true` boolean otherwise it will return `null` if the property accessor is non-public.

Answer (score 3):

`GetProperties` with `System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic` flag returns all of them: `private`, `internal`, `protected` and `protected internal`.

Comment: I take it you can't get any more granular than that.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have added the word 'only' to my questions to make it clear that I would like to get only those.

Comment: You can't get more granular data than just `public` or `nonpublic`.