# How to get value of the default layout from _ViewStart.cshtml in MVC/Razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have an extension methods for MVCs `Controller` class that needs to know what the current default layout file is (i.e. the value from `_ViewStart.cshtml`).

The code is in a library, so I only have the controller to start from. The code below basically allows any controller action to always return a PartialPage, but conditionally assigns the default layout layout (making it a full View) *if it was not in response to an Ajax request* (e.g. to see the entire page for debugging).

e.g.

```
public static void RenderMode(this Controller controller)
{
     if (!controller.Request.IsAjaxReuest())
     {
         controller.ViewBag.Layout = ????????;
     }
}
```

**So the question is, how do you get at the default layout page value from code?**

Comment: The `_ViewStart` file is always the first view which is executed by the `RazerView` object. It is a `internal readonly` field "ViewStartFileName" inside `RazorViewEngine`. A _ViewStart file can define per folder the default layout of all views below. Inside a global action filter it would be easier to change the layout conditionally. The problem is the controller doesn't know about the created view "yet".

Comment: @Andreas: So basically, no, then? I can't get at it. :)

Comment: Not without dirty tricks ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/q/7575577/1484933

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for the info. Workaround posted below. Let me know if you ever find a better alternative. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment from Andreas (thanks), the required setting is buried away in the RazorViewEngine class and is not accessible.

### Update Sep 2015 - New Solution!

We recently found a better way to do this, without the invasive changes to any action code.

### Steps:

- Inherit all controllers from a common `BaseController` class.
- Add an `OnActionExecuting` override method to the `BaseController`.
- Call `RenderMode()` from inside that method - so this will happen for all requests, before the action gets called.
- Change `RenderMode()` to set `ViewBag.Layout = null` for Ajax page requests.
- Inside _ViewStart.cshtml add code to set the layout to a ViewBag value.

**BaseController.cs - RenderMode()**

```
public void RenderMode(string layout)
{
    if (IsPartialPage)
    {
        // Wipe any existing layout page
        ViewBag.Layout = null;
        return;
    }
    ViewBag.Layout = layout;
}
```

**ViewStart.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = (string)ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.Layout;
}
```

The end result is that you can return a `View()` or a `PartialView()` as normal and the view will be rendered as a full or partial view *based instead on the "ajax" check done before the action executes*. This has simplified our websites significantly as we can use more of the standard scaffolded code *as-is*.

---

### Previous solution (now obsolete)

My workaround is therefore to pass a default layout to the `RenderMode` extension method:

### i.e.

```
public static void RenderMode(this Controller controller, layout)
{
     if (!controller.Request.IsAjaxReuest())
     {
         controller.ViewBag.Layout = layout;
     }
}
```

and call from any controller like this (or using a constant known to the app):

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var vm = new SomeViewModel();
    RenderMode("~/views/shared/_MainLayout.cshtml");
    return PartialView(vm);
}
```

The end result is a partial view when called from Ajax or a full view, using `_mainLayout.cshtml`, if called directly.