# GetProperty Method returns null C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

Can someone please explain, why does the GetProperty method in System.Type returns null for properties that are declared as 'internal' but works for 'public'.

```
internal class Test{      
  public string ALocal { get; set; }
  internal string SLocal { get; set; }}

var test = new Test();
var testType = test.GetType();

var aProp = testType.GetProperty("ALocal"); => returns string Type
var sProp = testType.GetProperty("SLocal"); => returns null
```

I understand differences between internal or public modifiers.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575577/how-do-i-iterate-through-internal-properties-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GetProperty Method returns only public properties by default.
You should include following flags

```
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static
```

to get internal type

MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `BindingFlags.Static` isn't needed since it's an instance member.